# Php mail Contact Form Error

Tags: php, sendmail, contact-form

I have bought hosting and created web mail.But mail function of contact form is not working in my hosting. It prints" Error".I didnt understand where I am wrong. I have searhed in google, looked the examples but I didnt solve my problem.Please help me. Thanks.
**Edit info:** When I bougt hosting, it was windows hosting. The maik function was working. But, I passed the linux hosting, then created again mail in cpanel. But, now the mail function is not working. Thanks again.

**Edit2:** Hi this code worked in windows hosting. I think problem is originated from linux hosting...
This is my code:

contact.html

```
<html>
<form action="contact_form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactform">

            <fieldset class="row">

                <legend>Contact me :)</legend>

                <p>
                    <label for="your-name">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="your-name" class="input-xlarge">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="your-email">Your Email <span class="required">(required)</span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="your-email" class="input-xlarge" required>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="your-subject">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="your-subject" class="input-xlarge">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="your-message">Your message <span class="required">(required)</span></label>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" id="your-message" class="input-xxlarge" required placeholder="What do you want to say?"></textarea>
                </p>

                <!-- This is hidden for normal users -->
                <div class="hidden">
                    <label>
                        Do not fill out this field
                        <input name="s_check">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="primary" value="Send Message">
                </p>

                <p hidden id="response"></p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
</html>
```

contact_form.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to = 'info@xyz.com';

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']); //sender's name
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']); //sender's email
        $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']); // the subject

        echo $name."<br/>";
        echo $email."<br/>";
        echo $subject."<br/>";

        //The message you will receive in your mailbox
        $msg  = "From : $name \r\n";  //add sender's name to the message
        $msg .= "e-Mail : $email \r\n";  //add sender's email to the message
        $msg .= "Subject : $subject \r\n\n"; 
        $msg .= "---Message--- \r\n".stripslashes($_POST['message'])."\r\n\n";                        $msg .= "---User information--- \r\n"; //Title
        $msg .= "User IP : ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\r\n"; //Sender's IP
        $msg .= "Browser info : ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]."\r\n"; //User agent
        $msg .= "User come from : ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; //Referrer

        if  (mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")){

        //Message sent!

        echo nl2br("
        <div class=\"MsgSent\">
            <h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
            <p>Thank you <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message is sent!<br /> I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
        </div>
       ");
       exit;
        }
        else{

        // Display error message if the message failed to send
        echo "
        <div class=\"MsgError\">
            <h1>Error!!</h1>
            <p>Sorry <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message failed to send. Try later!</p>
        </div>";
        exit;
        }

}


?>
```

Comment: try this simple version and check if it send a mail `mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);`

If this works make just add more info

See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have written like you said, but it didnt send mail :/

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Thank you <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message is sent!<br />
<p>Sorry <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message failed to send. Try later!</p>
```

Should be

```
<p>Thank you <b>{$name}</b>, your message is sent!<br />
<p>Sorry <b>{$name}</b>, your message failed to send. Try later!</p>
```

Also not sure why you are using nl2br a simple echo should suffice.

Comment: Thanks but, it didnt work again. The mail function is problemmatic. Is it about php.ini?

Comment: Generally on a cPanel server mail() works out of the box. Try Perry's suggestion and if that doesn't work contact your host. Can you also paste the full error message you are getting.

Comment: in contact_form.php, I have written this code: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $send = mail("info@XYZ.com","My Subject","This is header");
 if($send)
  echo "Sent";
 else
  echo "Error";
}
else{
 echo "Error submit";
}
But it prints error.

Comment: just type in this in a blank file and run it in your browser: <?php mail('YOUREMAIL', 'test email', 'test email'); ?> and nothing else. What do you see?

Comment: yeah, I am changing my hosting linux to windows. I think the source og problem is hosting problems. In windows hosting the mail function is working.. I do not know reason but it was working. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You'd have a harder time getting mail() to work properly on Windows than you would on Linux. Check your code again and see what the error messages say, they contain useful information.

Comment: This code worked in windows hosting.. I am now interacting with my hosting services why the mail function is not working in linux hosting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said elsewhere, the `mail()` function is problematic -- it is very low level and not easy to work with.

You would be much better advised to not use it at all -- there are several very good mailer classes for PHP that are much easier to use, give much better results, and are significantly more powerful.

My suggestion is to use [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/); it's very easy to use -- as you can see from [this example page](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicMail). But there are several other alternatives libraries available as well.